# Predicting based upon categorical data and one numeric datatype

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I would like to determine what variables from this sample data would be best predictors for CallHandleTimeSeconds.

Im thinking it would be a combination of CreditRating, EligibleForAssistance, TypeOfCall, AmtInArrears but unsure about how to do this. I understand the process when all the variables are numeric but categorical variables make my head spin! Please help, because I learn best from examples then I can basically plug and play other categorical variables in the future.

Like if CreditRating = Good;, EligibleForAssistance = T, TypeOfCall = 2, and AmtInArrears = 21 then CallHandleTimeSeconds = 432?????

```
 CreditRating = c("Poor", "Poor", "Good", "Good", "Average", "Poor", "Average") 
 EligibleForAssistance = c("T", "F", "T", "F", "T", "T","T") 
 Season = c(1,2,1,3,2,3,4)
 TypeOfCall = c(1,1,2,3,3,1,2)
 NumberOfDaysAccountOpen = c(111,2321,33,322,2321,343,785)
 AmtInArrears = c(0,0,0,22,232,2,0)
 CallHandleTimeSeconds= c(123,232,543,239,230,400,210)

 SampleData = data.frame(CreditRating,      EligibleForAssistance,Season,TypeOfCall,NumberOfDaysAccountOpen,AmtInArrears,CallHandleTimeSeconds)
```

What test would I run? Logistic Regression? Please help.

Comment: logistic regression, why? outcome variable does not seem binary. and hope you have more data than above,

Comment: Yes, I have about 15 million rows. That was just an example of the data set. Sorry I should have been more clear. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simulate more data:

```
> CR <- factor(as.vector(rmultinom(100, 2, prob=c(0.1,0.2,0.8))) + 1, labels = c("Poor", "Average", "Good"))
> EFA <- as.logical(rbinom(300, 1, 0.7))
> S <- factor(as.vector(rmultinom(100, 3, prob=c(0.1,0.2,0.8))) + 1)
> TOC <- factor(as.vector(rmultinom(100, 2, prob=c(0.1,0.2,0.8))) + 1)
> NODAO <- trunc(runif(300, 200, 500))
> AIA <- rnbinom(300, 1, 0.05)
> CHTS <- as.integer(runif(300, 100, 600))
```

As you can see, categorical variables(CreditRating, Season, TypeOfCall) are coded as *factors*, i.e. you should do something like:

```
> CR <- factor(CreditRating)
> S <- factor(Season)
```

etc. (logical variables as EligibleForAssistance are ok.)

Then you can fit your model, e.g.

```
> fit <- lm(CHTS ~ CR + EFA + S + TOC + NODAO + AIA)
> round(summary(fit)$coefficients,2)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   358.65      41.30    8.68     0.00
CRAverage      -6.25      22.29   -0.28     0.78
CRGood         25.78      29.41    0.88     0.38
EFATRUE         5.81      18.13    0.32     0.75
S2              6.63      21.37    0.31     0.76
S3            -17.88      30.05   -0.60     0.55
S4            -47.76      33.88   -1.41     0.16
TOC2            7.62      21.36    0.36     0.72
TOC3           20.16      28.76    0.70     0.48
NODAO          -0.03       0.10   -0.34     0.73
AIA            -0.38       0.47   -0.81     0.42
```

and you can interpret your results. The expected mean value of CallHandleTimeSeconds is:

- if CR="Poor", EFA=FALSE, S=1, TOC=1, NODAO=0 and AIA=0: $358.65$ (the intercept)
- if CR="Average":
  $$358.65-6.25=352.4$$
- if CR="Average" and EFA=TRUE:
  $$358.65-6.25+5.81=358.21$$
- if CR="Good", EFA=TRUE and NODAO=500:
  $$358.65+25.78+5.81-0.03\times 500=375.24$$

and so on.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to reproduce the problem and lay it out very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think categorical variables are an issue. This is fairly easily handled by most statistical programs, including R. A google search will provide you will lots of sample code. One example is at: http://data.princeton.edu/R/linearModels.html

It does appear that your outcome variable `CallHandleTimeSeconds` is numeric and likely best served by a simple linear model. The real issue is whether this variable is normally distributed. time rarely is. There are many ways of addressing this...discussed on this website....including taking the log(outcome) variable and modeling that.